# TypeError: coercing to Unicode

Tags: python

New guy in Python here.

This is the Python code:

```
z = json.dumps("/opt/test/etc/file.json)
print(z)
```

The result is:

> TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

How do I make it work? I want to print out the output of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) you confused the function. Is `json.dump` and no `Json.dumps`. The `s` is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

See the docs for `json.dumps` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html
It takes a JSON object, not a filename. If you're trying to load a file containing JSON, you want `json.load()` so do this:

```
with open('foo.json') as f:
  obj = json.load(f)
  print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json.dumps(...)
```

Takes the structure such as a dict and dumps it to a string. You would use it like so:

```
my_val = { "key" : "value"}
s = json.dumps(my_val)
print(s) 
# outputs something like '{ "key" : "value"}'
```

I believe if you're trying to load file "file.json" you would do something like

```
import json
with open("file.json") as f:
    z  = json.load(f)
    print(z)
```